# (Python) OpenCV frames sending through socket

Tags: python, sockets, opencv

i'm trying send OpenCV's frames through sockets, like the code below.
The problem is that the video ends up coming out weird, divided into multiple rows or columns.

(Python 2.7)

ob: This code is not mine.

source: http://answers.opencv.org/question/69123/sending-opencv-frames-through-udp-socket-python/

Client:

```
import socket
import numpy as np
import cv2


UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 5005

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
while 1:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    d = frame.flatten()
    s = d.tostring()
    for i in range(20):
        sock.sendto(s[i*46080:(i+1)*46080], (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Server:

```
import socket
import numpy as np
import cv2


UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 5005

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
s = ""
while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(46080)
    s += data
    if len(s) == (46080*20):
        frame = np.fromstring(s, dtype='uint8')
        frame = frame.reshape(480, 640, 3)
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        s = ""
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```